# Laravel generateurl function

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
<td><a href="http://example.com/forum/{{ $forum->seo_name }}/{{ $forum->id }}">{{ $forum->name }}</a></td>
```

I wan't to use

`{!! generateForumLink($forum->seo_name, $forum->id) !!}`

how can I do it?

I have created simple function in controller:

```
public function generateForumURL($name, $id)
{
    return "http://localhost/".$name."/".$id;
}
```

how can I use it it template? Maybe exists better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1: Creating a helper

I generally create a `helpers.php` file in the `app` folder, and add it to autoload section of `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php" // Add this file
    ]
},
```

In `helpers.php`, add the function as follows:

```
function generateForumURL($name, $id)
{
    // Using the url() helper, so you don't have to manually switch between
    // localhost and the production website name
    return url($name . "/" . $id);
}
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` when you're done.

### Method 2: [Defining an accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Another way would be to simply add a `getUrlAttribute` to the `Forum` model, that returns the URL:

```
class Forum extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return url($this->name . '/' . $this->id);
    }

}
```

You can now use `$forum->url` as a string anywhere you like.

---

### Using the link template

You can save the template as a view (I normally do it in a `partials` folder) and include it wherever you need:

File `views/forums/partials/link.blade.php`:

```
@if(isset($forum))
    <a href="{{ $forum->url }}">{{ $forum->name }}</a>
@endif
```

Include it in another views as follows:

```
@include('forums.partials.link', ['forum' => $forum])
```

Comment: And how can I use it now? I'm tried   {{ generateForumURL('test', 'test') }} and I'm got `Call to undefined function generateForumURL()`

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\myadmin\htdocs\app\helpers.php on line 2` line 2 : `public function generateForumURL($name, $id)` first is `<?php`

Comment: Oops, my bad. As the error clearly explains, remove the `public` from the helper function.